# Deixar foto arredondada igual whatsapp

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile

Comecei a pouco tempo na área de desenvolvimento para Android.

Gostaria de saber qual recurso utilizo, no XML, para deixar uma foto arredondada igual a um contato do Whatsapp.

Já uso para algumas imagens a borda arredondada, criando um `XML drawable` com o `shape`. Mas creio que não seja esse o caso.

Comment: Eu utilizo a lib do bootstrap para Android. Aqui está a lib com os exemplos abaixo: https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um círculo simples com borda branca e conteúdo transparente:

```
// res/drawable/circle.xml

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Depois faz um layerlist drawable:

```
// res/drawable/img.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>

</layer-list>
```

E então coloca como pano de fundo pro ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img"/>
```

Vai ter algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No caso eu não quero pegar uma imagem específica, mas sim uma foto tirada do app e depois adicionar ao contato numa ListView. Ou seja, como eu vou atribuir o item do img.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar [isto](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) ou

```
public class CircleTransform extends BitmapTransformation {

public CircleTransform(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
    if (toTransform == null) return null;

    int size = Math.min(toTransform.getWidth(), toTransform.getHeight());
    int x = (toTransform.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    int y = (toTransform.getHeight() - size) / 2;

    // TODO this could be acquired from the pool too
    Bitmap squared = Bitmap.createBitmap(toTransform, x, y, size, size);

    Bitmap result = pool.get(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    if (result == null) {
        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(squared, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    float r = size / 2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    return result;
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return  getClass().getName();
}
```

}

ai recuperar na atividade que você quer,exemplo:

```
Glide.with(ivUser.getContext()).load(urlPhotoUser).centerCrop().transform(new CircleTransform(ivUser.getContext())).override(40,40).into(ivUser);
```